# How w3.org authors translate a visual angle in height to measure the dimension of a CSS pixel's reference?

Tags: css, math

Im wondering where they pull the number 0.26mm, here the link of the documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#absolute-lengths

Here the authors statement:

> The reference pixel is the visual angle of one pixel on a device with
>   a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm’s
>   length. For a nominal arm’s length of 28 inches, the visual angle is
>   therefore about 0.0213 degrees. For reading at arm’s length, 1px thus
>   corresponds to about 0.26 mm (1/96 inch).

I would understand the calculus behind this result. How they have fuond 0.0213degrees? how they have found that 1px thus corresponds to about 0.26 mm? that is my very question please

any hint would be great,

thanks

Comment: @jhpratt thanks to explain your vote jhpratt, it is really appreciable to understand the rationale behind the move, and allows me to explain further :). I think it is relevant for stackoverflow since it could allow a lot of developer to better understand the functioning of their program, and the rationale behind their working tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an arm length of 28 inches, the circumference of the circle is 28 * 2pi = 175.929 inches. We can then take the size of a pixel (1/96 inch, per the spec) and divide it by the circumference to determine the proportion of the circle that is a single pixel. ([1/96]/175.929). Multiplying this value by 360 converts the proportion to degrees. The final calculation is (1/96)/(28*2pi)*360 = 0.0213°.

As to the second part of your question, they didn't find that 1px is 1/96 of an inch — that's actually how an inch is defined in CSS. If you create a line with length 1in, it will *always* be 96px, regardless of the pixel density of your screen.

Comment: Note that _technically_, this should be calculated by using the chord length, not the arc length, but with a visual field this small the difference is negligible.

Comment: thanks for your answer! would you agree to add the chord length's method? it would allow the readers to have the technically compliant's method, also how you pass from 0.0213° to 0.26mm please?

Comment: As to the physical distance, CSS just defines an inch to be 96 pixels. I'm not sure why they settled on that, but that's how it is. I can add the chord method if you'd like, though it'll be a bit verbose — it will almost certainly not have any differences within the three significant figures provided.